# How Could I limit the string to 12 Characters Only

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a function that adds dashes to a phone number field how would I limit the chars in this field to 12 chars only?

```js
function dash(el, after) {
  after = after || 3;
  var v = el.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, ''),
    reg = new RegExp(".{" + after + "}", "g")
  el.value = v.replace(reg, function(a, b, c) {
    return a + '-';
  });
}

var el = document.getElementById('phone');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (el.value.length <= 8) {
    dash(this, 3);
  } else {
    el.value.length++;
  }
  if (el.value.length >= 12) {
    el.value.length = el.substring(0, 12);
  }
});
```

```html
<span>Phone</span><input id="phone" class="comInputc" name="phone" type="text">
```

Comment: 12 characters with dash?

Comment: 10 with the dashes which would be 12.

Comment: `el.substring(0, 12);` produces an error. Should be `el.value.substring(0, 12);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the HTML [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#maxlength) attribute:

```
<span>Phone</span><input id="phone" class="comInputc" name="phone" type="text" maxlength="12">
```

Comment: Great answer! I was trying it through javascript the hard way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Let's go one step further and use a [better tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel) that has semantics and regular expression pattern match validation built in.

Try to enter anything other than numbers and dashes in the specified format below and then click the Submit button.

```html
<form>
  <label for="phone">Enter your phone number:</label>

  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
         pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
         placeholder="ie. 123-456-7890"
         required>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```